# Does Ubuntu no longer provide new legacy image?

Tags: 20.04

Does anyone know where to download 20.04.2 LTS legacy image?
I've checked the place I used to download the legacy version of ubuntu image.

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-legacy-server/releases/focal/release/

But there is no 20.04.2 released and I saw a questionnaire asking the reason to download legacy images.
So I am wondering does anyone heard there is a policy change from ubuntu to not release legacy images?

Comment: Even if you download the 20.04.1 it will upgrade to the newer / newest version during or after the installation.

Comment: Check [this](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/focal/ubuntu-20.04-live-server-amd64.iso). Also you can try to ask developers directly [on community](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/poll-about-possible-netboot-mini-iso-revival-in-future-ubuntu-releases/19457). They are trying to break user habits by removing mini.iso.

Comment: I have added this issue in the Ubuntu bug tracker to see if they will release a legacy image for 20.04.2 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1933442